# Copy file to clipboard as text/html

Tags: x11, clipboard

I would like to copy the contents of a file to the X11 `CLIPBOARD` target `text/html` using the command line.

Ideally, this would be as portable as possible across different flavors of Linux and possibly other Unices.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the legacy UNIX flavors but under redhat and debian compatible linux distros, there exist a binary called `xclip`, which does exactly what you want.

If you don't have it on your system, you can install it

Redhat variants

```
yum install xclip
```

Debian based

```
apt-get install xclip
```

Comment: As far as I know, only `xclip` versions built from SVN support setting the target. The versions shipped by default in Arch and Debian, at least, are not bleeding edge enough.

Comment: @PythonNut xclip in Debian jessie (current stable, version 0.12+svn84) does support `xclip -t $target`.

Comment: @Gilles you're right. However, I just tested it in Arch, and it doesn't work. :(